# How to write an iterator in javascript for a simple AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm stumped on this. I'm trying to send an AJAX call by iterating over all the inputs and collecting their `val()` which is a string.

So that my params would hopefully look like this:

```
 "action"=>"create",
 "type"=>"zip",
 "value"=> ["12", "13", "14", "14", "15", "16"],
 "controller"=>"admin/distributions",
 "email_id"=>"3"}
```

This is what I have, but its giving me an `[Object object]` as a value :

```
$(".all_of_morris").live("click", function(){
  id = window.location.href.split("/")[5]
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/emails/" + id + "/distributions",
    dataType: "script",
    data: { $.each($(".morris input"), function(){
      value: $(this).val();
    }),
      type: "zip" }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an array for the value property, you can use the [jquery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function:

```
$(".all_of_morris").live("click", function(){
    var data = {};
    data.value = $(".morris input").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    data.type = 'zip';
    //..etc
    id = window.location.href.split("/")[5]
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/emails/" + id + "/distributions",
        dataType: "script",
        data: data
    });
});
```

Comment: Strange, this only returned the last value

Comment: @Trip: That may have something to do with the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: @Brad, what about the get() ?

Comment: @Trip: Get typically secludes the result to the first option. i.e. if you had `$('input').get()` it returns the first input off the stack. (Though I've never used it on an array result, so not sure).

Comment: Hmm.. good to know. Yah its strange, if I do it in the screen, or in Josiah's JSFiddle, it pulls an array. but on my server, when it passes, it only receives the last zip.

Comment: @Trip - make sure you have a valid selector that pulls all the elements, not just the last one.

Comment: It does pull all the elements in my console, but it does not send any data to the server in the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

```
$('.morris input').serialize();
```

And you don't want to an `.each` within the json object. If pre-processing is required, build the payload in a variable first using whatever means you deem necessary, then pass that variable to the `.ajax` call.

e.g.

```
var value = /*get value array */; ...
var dataToPass = {
  'action' : 'create',
  'value': value,
  'type' : 'zip',
  ...
};
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: dataToPass,
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns an object because the `each` of JQuery merely executes its contents, not return it. The data key also accepts strings as value so you could iterate through the contents, generate something like `"action=create&type=zip&..."` and then give that array as value for the data key.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: { value:  $('.morris input').map( function() {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get(),
        type: 'zip'
      },
```